# Forward declaration and ComPtr

Tags: com, forward-declaration

I have this simple case:

```
struct ID3D11Buffer;

class Object3D
{
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> indBuffer; // use of undefined type 'ID3D11Buffer' in VisualStudio 2013
    std::shared_ptr<ID3D11Buffer> a; // ok
}
```

As you can see forward declaration works with`shared_ptr`, but fails with `ComPtr`. And I curious why?

Comment: shared_ptr reference counting is external to the wrapped object, so only a pointer is needed (and here's why you deleter is not an issue: stackoverflow.com/questions/20985667/…). COM reference counting requires calls to `AddRef` and `Release` so it requires the type to be defined (just guessing, I don't have access to `WRL::ComPtr`)